# Пересортировка таблицы по class'ам

Tags: javascript

Имеется определенная табличная разметка. В ней распологаются элементы. Задача состоит в том, чтоб при загрузке страницы, таблица пересортировывалась\пересобиралась таким образом, чтоб сначала выводились все tr с классом "status_on_sort", затем все tr с классом "status_off_sort" и в последнюю очередь все tr с классом "zero_sort", или другими классами, отличными от выше описанных. Данные классы приобретаются родительскими tr'ками от класса картинок и немного дополняются.

В том варианте, что у меня, скрипт не очень корректно срабатывает. Он вырывает нужные мне tr'ки и создает из них новые. Полагаю, что ошибка может быть связанна с этой строчкой:"c.appendChild(a)". Но не уверен в этом. Прошу помощи. Буду бесконечно благодарен всем откликнувшимся. :)

Разметка html:

```
<div id="object_data_body">

<table>
<tbody id="block">



<tr> <!-- класс присвоить-->
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <a href="#" class="link">this is link</a>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <font color="#000">
                            <b>нейтрально</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <span>
                            <img class="zero" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <a href="#" class="link">this is link</a>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <font color="#000">
                            <b>нейтрально</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <span>
                            <img class="zero" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>




<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <a href="#" class="link">this is link</a>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <font color="#000">
                            <b>плохо</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <span>
                            <img class="status_off" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <a href="#" class="link">this is link</a>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <font color="#000">
                            <b>хорошо</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <span>
                            <img class="status_on" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <a href="#" class="link">this is link</a>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <font color="#000">
                            <b>плохо</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <span>
                            <img class="status_off" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <a href="#" class="link">this is link</a>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <font color="#000">
                            <b>хорошо</b>
                        </font>
                    </td>

                    <td align="right">
                        <span>
                            <img class="status_on" title="оповещение" src="https://home.yastatic.net/morda-logo/i/afisha_color_62.png">
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Код JS:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var key = '_sort';

for(var i=0, last, parent; i < images.length;i++) {
last = undefined;
parent = images[i].parentNode;

while(parent = parent.parentNode) {
    if(parent.tagName && parent.tagName.toLowerCase() == "tr") {
        last = parent;
    }
}

if(last != undefined) {
    last.classList.add(images[i].className + key);
}
}

//************************************************************************

var c = document.querySelector("#block");
Array.apply(null,document.querySelectorAll("#object_data_body tr"))
.sort(function(a, b) {
a = a.classList;
a = a.contains('status_on_sort') ? -2 : a.contains('status_off_sort') ? 0 : 2;
b = b.classList;
b = b.contains('status_on_sort') ? -2 : b.contains('status_off_sort') ? 0 : 2;
return a < b ? -2 : a > b ? 2 : 0
})
.forEach(function(a) {
c.appendChild(a)
});
```

Вот тут вариант корретной работы скрипта до срабатывания скрипта сортировки(чтоб нагляднее была суть проблемы.)
http://jsfiddle.net/malefikus13/L0bepeLv/

Вот тут образец с моим конечным вариантом, где сортировка срабатывает не так, как задуманно.
http://jsfiddle.net/malefikus13/t7tn6djg/

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален. надеюсь, хоть кто нибудь не пройдет мимо :)

Comment: не ужели ни кто ни чем не сможет подсобить? )) Народ, хелп плиз!